# Translate mysql script to sqlite script

Tags: javascript, database, html

I'm trying to make a mobile app using HTML5. I made a model in MySQL workbench. Now I want to translate my mysql script to sqlite script for put the script in my javascript file then create some websql tables.

So, is it possible?

Sorry for bad english, my first language is not english

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple guide for converting MySQL dump file to SQLite dump file

[How-to: Convert mysql to sqlite](http://www.jbip.net/content/how-convert-mysql-sqlite)

Comment: How can I see the script after the conversion?

Comment: Using <mysql-dump-file-name>.db, indeed you should find a file with db extension that have same name as your MySQL dump file